# Adding USB device to KVM (using virtual manager). Everytime I try, device adds itself with other number

Tags: usb, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to use a Ledger Nano S (cryptocurrency wallet) inside a VM using Virtual Manager on my Ubuntu host (16.04) and Ubuntu guest (16.04). Everytime I open my Ledger and click on the 'Bitcoin' wallet for example, I can see in `dmesg -w` that it disconnects itself from the previous number and adds itself with a new number

```
[ 1277.256729] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 18
[ 1277.569196] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[ 1277.716519] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2c97, idProduct=0001
[ 1277.716525] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1277.716529] usb 1-1: Product: Nano S
[ 1277.716532] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Ledger
[ 1277.716535] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 0001
[ 1277.723273] hid-generic ...: hiddev0,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Device [Ledger Nano S] on usb-...
```

When I add a new hardware in Virt-Manager's menu, it registers the current number that Nano has and won't update it unless I restart virt-manager. Anyways, even if the number on virt-manager is still the number that ledger has, I cannot start the virtual machine because it says that my ubuntu (host) is already using it.

Is there a way to prevent ubuntu host from using the ledger nano s? How to disconnect it? I tried to search on how to find devices being used, but only found for hard drives, usb drives, etc. Not for generic devices like Ledger Nano S.

Comment: disconnecting from the guest os? or you meant host os?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, you want the device to be disconnected from the host?

Comment: Ok I see that it's a USB type device in that case my suggestion should work!

Comment: I need to disconnect from the host to use it in my virtual machine

Comment: So follow my tip and you should be good to go!

Comment: Could you explain me better? If I add myself to vboxusers, what happens? I need to disconnect from the host os, right? By disconnect you mean unplug and then plug again?

Comment: My mistake thought you were using Virtualbox let me look up that for kvm

Comment: Please look at this: https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/USB_Host_Device_Assigned_to_Guest and https://serverfault.com/questions/666210/attaching-usb-dongle-to-kvm-vm

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen thanks by the answer, but I'm having problems with this specific device. First, because everytime I press some buttons, it reattaches itself with a different usb number. And even if I manae to add it to the VM with its current number, it's already being used by my host OS and I don't know why